# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() web Service

Tags: php, json, web-services, foreach

hey i've tried to DECODE my JSON data like this : 
`

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/php/service.php?rquest=searcht&user=".$user);
$final_res = html_entity_decode($json);
foreach ($final_res as $thedata->user)
            {
            foreach ($thedata as $value) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td  ><? echo $value['No']?>  </td>
            <td><?echo $value['user']?></td>
   }
}
```

`
the decode data works fine with output JSON, but when i tried to foreach the JSON data, its doesnt work, but..in other case i use this foreach the same way to print my data with Select * data query to other page. its work, but i use this foreach to same way, but the output is Invalid argument supplied for foreach() please tell me if i do a mistake...

Comment: Try var_dump() to see what kind of data the parameter is which you are passing to the foreach() loop.

Comment: where are you decoding the json? that doesn't have a call to json_decode at all.

Comment: update i've been decode like this : $final_res = html_entity_decode($json);
$final_res1 = json_decode(stripslashes($final_res)); but foreach doesnt work

Comment: then the result is NULL when i try json_decode

Answer (score 0):

you have not used `json_decode`, the content you are getting from `file_get_contents` is a string, apply `json_decode($final_res)` to get the content in an array form.

Comment: $final_res = html_entity_decode($json); i decode it in there, i try with json_decode but the output is NULL...

Comment: update i've decode the data like this : 
$final_res = html_entity_decode($json);
   $final_res1 = json_decode(stripslashes($final_res));

Comment: update i've been decode my data li this :
 $final_res = html_entity_decode($json);
$final_res1 = json_decode(stripslashes($final_res));  but foreach doesnt work

Comment: what do you get for `echo $json`;